# Turtlebot doesn't move in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, eband-local-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to add different local planner to my ROS navigation stack, eband_local_planner is one among them. I'm using the navfn as global planner and eband as local planner which I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/utexas-bwi/eband_local_planner). I created a [launch file](http://freetexthost.com/qsirncgjnb) for the stack. The configuration files are taken from [here](https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot/tree/master/segbot_navigation/config/segbotv2). Once I launch the file Gazebo gives out exact local and global path, however the turtlebot doesn't move in the simulation. I'm also attaching the [video link](https://www.magisto.com/video/YEEVIFNRHzFpQwFgCzE) of the process.

Can anybody point out the mistake with the process.

EDIT #1
Added the rqt_graph [here](http://postimg.org/image/8wdpmwfiv/)

Thanks,
Karthi.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244159/turtlebot-doesn%27t-move-in-gazebo/) by [Karthikeyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27730/karthikeyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

could you control turtlebot by using teleop?

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

if could, it might because your navigation stack did pub. topic on `/cmd_vel_mux`

sometimes, rviz control robot base by topic `/cmd_vel`

i suggest you check your node nest first `rqt_graph`

then you would see if you exactly get you nodes communicate well..

---

Originally posted by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) with karma: 188 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karthikeyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27730/karthikeyan/) on 2016-09-23**:
Hi, Yes you are correct the nav stack publish the topic `/cmd_vel_mux`. How to change this to topic `/cmd_vel`